# Install libxml2.8 on RHEL 6

Tags: installation, rpm, rhel6, dependencies, glibc

I want to install the software TinyOWS on a RHEL 6 server. I followed the instructions:

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/mapserver/tinyows-1.1.0.tar.bz2
tar xvjf tinyows-1.1.0.tar.bz2
cd tinyows-1.1.0
./configure
make
make install
```

But I couldn't complete the installation because the TinyOWS has a dependency on a library **libxml2 version 2.8** or higher. The version of **libxml2** on my RHEL6 server is 2.7. The reason why **libxml2.8** is a bug in the older versions of ***libxml2*** that is described [here](http://mapserver.org/tinyows/libxmlschemagmlbug.html):

So, it seems that I have to install the libxml2 library version 2.8 or higher on a RHEL 6 server.
I tried to run:

```
 yum update libxml2
```

But the highest version of ***libxml2*** on the RHEL repository is 2.7.6.

I tried to workaround the problem by downloading the **libxml2-2.8.0-1.x86_64 rpm** file from [xmlsoft.org](ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/), but when I tried to install the downloaded .rpm I got a lot of unmet dependency warnings:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libxml2-2.8.0-1.x86_64 (/libxml2-2.8.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: libxml2-2.8.0-1.x86_64 (/libxml2-2.8.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.3.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: libxml2-2.8.0-1.x86_64 (/libxml2-2.8.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: libxml2-2.8.0-1.x86_64 (/libxml2-2.8.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

I'm quite afraid of messing up the system by installing all these dependencies. For example, I read that the **glibc 2.14** library is unavailable for RHEL 6.

What would you recommend to to to install **libxml2.8** on RHEL 6? Or is there any other way how I could 'apply a patch' to my current installation of libxml2.7?

Comment: (Why do you need libxml2.8?)

Comment: I need libxml2.8 because: I'm trying to install the software TinyOWS http://mapserver.org/trunk/tinyows/ and when I try to install it from source, it complains because it has a dependency on libxml2.8. Tinyows won't run properly with libxml2.7 because of a bug in libxml2.7 that is explained here: http://mapserver.org/tinyows/libxmlschemagmlbug.html